# Получить связанные элементы из таблиц Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, backend, many-to-many

У меня есть массив продуктов. И мне нужно получить теги с которыми связаны продукты (Product has many tags. Tags has many products). 
То есть, мне нужно получить продукт и все теги которые с ним связаны.

Допустим: `$products = "Массив с продуктами";`

```
$tags = Tag::all(); 
$tagEmpty = []; 
foreach ($tags as $tag){ 
    $tagEmpty[$tag->test] = $tag->tag_name; 
}
```

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы пытаетесь получить теги

Comment: $tags = Tag::all();

            $tagEmpty = [];


            foreach ($tags as $tag){

                $tagEmpty[$tag->test] = $tag->tag_name;

            }    
Здесь я получаю все tags . Но как правильно связать $products с $tags не знаю...

Comment: А как у вас теги связаны с продуктами? Покажите миграцию от тегов и продуктов. Добавьте в ответ. Если вам нужно выбрать теги для текущего продута, то нужно использовать Tag::where('product' => $product), а не получать их все сразу

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать Elequent, то вам нужно пользоваться Моделями и описывать внутри них связи между таблицами. Покажите ваши модели